# Trying to group data by time and sum values for each month

Tags: r, group-by

I would like to group my data by months and show the total values of each month.

This is the code I have

```
test2 <- test %>%
  mutate(date=as.Date(date,format="%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
  group_by(month = floor_date(date,"month"))%>%
  summarise(predicts=sum(predicts))
```

This is what I am getting

```
  predicts
1 74622000
```

Here is a sample of my data

```
        date    predicts
1    2012-01-02 17282.96
2    2012-01-03 17025.44
3    2012-01-04 16815.49
4    2012-01-05 16935.29
5    2012-01-06 18311.89
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue where we load `plyr` along with `dplyr` causing the `summarise` to get masked.  Specify `dplyr::summarise`, `dplyr::mutate` explicitly or redo in a fresh session with `dplyr` only loaded.  Also, wrap with `month` to extract the `month`, if that is what we need to group

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
test %>%
   dplyr::mutate(date=as.Date(date,format="%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
   group_by(month = floor_date(date,"month")) %>%
   dplyr::summarise(predicts=sum(predicts))
```